# PostgreSQL does not post a field

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm currently running through using Node-Express and Sequelize as the ORM for PostgreSQL. I am trying to test my API route when I noticed that my `todoId` is not being returned. When I check my table I see a null value even though I have `allowNull:false` set.

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.createTable('TodoItems', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      complete: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      todoId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Todos',
          key: 'id',
          as: 'todoId',
        },
      },
    }),
  down:(queryInterface/*, Sequelize*/) => queryInterface.dropTable('TodoItems'),
};
```

I have tried everything from dropping my database and creating a new one and migrations for the schema all over again. What I'm trying to achieve is to ensure that the value of the `todoId` column references and maps my the id of a separate table called `todo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The error was using a deprecated class methods